# using LINQ to search in 2 different elements in XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to use the following linq search, but to modify it so it will also search in users and admins.

`NAME`, `ID` and `PASS` are strings given for compare.  If all 3 match, then the program knows what kind of user it is, admin or user, and moves from there.  Otherwise, he isn't in any list and an error will show.

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load(@"c:\user.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> users = xelement.Elements();
foreach (var user in users)
{
  if((user.Element("Id").Value==ID)&&(user.Element("Username").Value==NAME)&&(user.Element("Password").Value==PASS))

}
```

The xml file is built like this:

```
<Data>    
    <UserList>
        <User Id="123" Username="abc" Password="abc123"></User>
    </UserList>
    <AdminList>
        <Admin Id="123" Username="abc" Password="abc123"></Admin>
    </AdminList>
</Data>
```

Comment: is this your complete xml ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i edited it, but more or less that is it, i use the xml file to store data, there are other info in it, i just want to search the admin and user "lists" to find if it is a match to my query

Comment: You're using the wrong `and` operator.  Use `&&`, not `&` - if((user.Element("Id").Value==ID) && (user.Element("Username").Value==NAME) && (user.Element("Password").Value==PASS))`

Comment: @Tim thx, made an error writing it. the problem remains, how to make him go thru <UserList> then  <AdminList> when the XElement loads all the data

Comment: Your query as written will not work as you expect.  First, you're querying on all the elements in the document, and secondly `Id`, `Username`, and `Password` are **attributes**, not elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code uses LINQ to XML classes, but you don't actually use any LINQ queries.

What you can do is:

1. Get admins and users separately

   ```
   XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\user.xml");
   var admins = xDoc.Root.Element("AdminList").Elements("Admin");
   var users = xDoc.Root.Element("UserList").Elements("User");
   ```
2. Concatenate them together:

   ```
   var adminsAndUsers
       = admins.Select(x => new { Element = x, Type = "Admin" })
               .Concat(users.Select(x => new { Element = x, Type = "User" }));
   ```
3. Query result collection looking for matching user. I used `(string)XAttribute` casting instead of `XAttribute.Value` property, because it's more safe to use (won't throw an exception when attribute does not exist).

   ```
   var user = adminsAndUsers.FirstOrDefault(
                     x => (string)x.Element.Attribute("Id") == ID &&
                          (string)x.Element.Attribute("Username") == NAME &&
                          (string)x.Element.Attribute("Password") == PASS);
   ```
4. Check query results

   ```
   if(user != null)
   {
       // user is there
       var type = user.Type;
   }
   else
   {
       // no user matches
   }
   ```

Comment: so it takes them both and combines them into one. don't get the "X=>" and while it's true that it will find if there is a user, how to know if its admin or user?

Comment: how can i tell what kind of user? can you explain the "x=>" part?

Comment: thx for the edit, now i understand. still how can i tell which is which? user or admin?

Comment: That's a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) syntax. Let me edit my solution to contain kind of user too.

Comment: just small something section 1 "ArrayList"? did you mean "UserList"?

Comment: Should be `AdminList.` Fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

structure

```
 public struct test
        {
            public bool isStudent;
            public string id;
            public string Username;
            public string Password;
        }



List<test>  users = doc.Descendants("User").Where(e => e.Attribute("Id").Value == "123").Select(e => new test{ isStudent = true, id = e.Attribute("Id").Value, Username = e.Attribute("Username").Value, Password = e.Attribute("Username").Value }).ToList();
              List<test>  admins = doc.Descendants("Admin").Where(e => e.Attribute("Id").Value == "123").Select(e => new test { isStudent = false, id = e.Attribute("Id").Value, Username = e.Attribute("Username").Value, Password = e.Attribute("Username").Value }).ToList();
            List<test> allTogether = users.Concat(admins).ToList();
            foreach (var xElement in allTogether)
            {
               //check if xElement property isStudent is true
            }
```

now in allTogether list you can check avery property that you need.